# Writing a macro to display pdfs in plain TeX under current and future versions of MikTeX

Tags: pdftex, miktex, miktex-update

**Note:**  As documented in the question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557699/pdftex-with-miniltx-not-working-as-expected/557715?noredirect=1#comment1406317_557715), I have, for the time being, solved this problem in a very ad hoc way.  But the problem resurfaces every time I get a new computer, so I'd like to know what is the **right** way to solve it --- a way that does not require so much improvisation.

I have hundreds of old Plain TeX files (rewriting these files is not a practical option).  I want to be able to apply pdftex to these files and get output that displays images.  I do this with a macro called "\graph" where the command

```
\graph{picname}{width}{height}
```

This displays the contents of picname.pdf, scaled to a height of "height".  (The parameter "width" is a historical relic and gets ignored.)

The code that implements this macro is

```
\def\graph#1#2#3{
     \includegraphics[height=#3]{#1.pdf}}

\newcount\pdfoutput\pdfoutput=1


\input c:/dos/belfry/graphixx
\input c:/dos/belfry/eplain
```

The file c:/dos/belfry/graphixx.tex starts with

```
\input c:/dos/belfry/miniltx
```

I have a Windows .bat file that automatically prepends the above lines to my .tex file whenever pdftex is invoked.  (I have a different .bat file that automatically appends a different set of lines whenever tex (as opposed to pdftex) is invoked, but that's not of concern here.)

I cannot remember why the \pdfoutput line is there.  I also cannot remember how my local versions of graphixx, eplain, and miniltx differ from the standard versions, except that I know my macro works when I invoke the local versions and not when I invoke the standard ones.  I'm not sure you need this information, because I suspect that answers to this question will tell me to start by ditching those non-standard versions anyway, but for the record I have posted all three files [here](http://www.panix.com/~wotw/texprobs).

(Mea culpa for having created such a mess in the first place.  In my defense, every time I've gotten a new computer and downloaded the latest version of MikTeX, I've found that it no longer runs the files that have always run in the past, and I've been in a great hurry to get up and running again, and the current situation is the result of my desperate flailing to make things work any way I could.  I should, of course, have kept better documentation.)

I can also, on request, share the full error logs I've gotten in the past, but again I suspect these are irrelevant, because I presume the solution will be to scrap everything and start from scratch to write a macro that will work and will be robust under whatever changes MikTeX is likely to make in the future.

**My question:**   The next time I get a new computer and download yet another revised version of MikTeX, what should I do to make my \graph macro work as intended?

Comment: sorry I didn't see the link. As expected you are using in part outdated  and changed files. Try to make a failing example that use up-to-date versions and official versions of the files

Comment: @UlrikeFischer :I'm sorry that I can not easily make a failing example now because (as noted in my other question) I've copied over  a bazillion old files so that nothing fails.  To create a failing example, I'd have to re-install the new MikTeX, create my failing example, and then (at least temporarily) re-instate my ad hoc solution by copying old files over new ones.  That's more than I have the energy for right now, but if you believe it would help you find an answer (and if you're interested) I'll try to find that energy soon.

Comment: But again---i'm not sure a failing example is necessary, since all I'm asking for is advice on how to start all over again from scratch writing a macro that will work.

Comment: well the general advice is: don't use home made files and commands if you can't handle them. Stick to the official interfaces. As soon as you start to change the files and to make local copies you are on your own.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer :  You seem to have misunderstood the question.  I am **asking** how to make my \graph macro work without using homemade files.

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of the earlier question (and you have still not shown a usable test file) Any issues that you are having are almost certainly unrelated to the miktex executable so having a current one or one that is 10 years old shouldn't make much difference. There may be differences in the tex macros you are using.

Comment: @WillO As Ulrike shows in her answer there is no reason why your macro shouldn't work you haven't shown usable code but the fragments you show load eplain (not relevant) and miniltx and (presumably) graphicx, and that is all you need. We can not tell you how to change them to work in the future, they should work now. (the definition is missing a `%` on the first line but that spurious space won't make a change in behaviour.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  The other question was "How do I solve this problem right now?".  The current question is "How do I solve this problem in a way that will survive through future MikTeX updates?".  Since my answer to the original question is NOT an answer to this question, the questions cannot be identical.

Comment: given that you have given no indication of your macros or why it doesn't work now or in future, the questions are essentially identical. Both have the same answer "it works now, if you get an error it is due to code not shown"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  I'm not sure this needs to be belabored, but I have no idea what is meant by "you have given no indication of your macros".  I posted the full text of all of the local input files that I invoke.  What else were you looking for?

Comment: You say the file  `The file c:/dos/belfry/graphixx.tex starts with...`  but what is the rest of the file? also since you show `\includegraphics` you must input graphics somewhere but you give no indication where,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  I posted **the entire file**.  Once again, it's at http://www.panix.com/~wotw/texprobs .  What are you looking for that's missing from there?  I'm genuinely baffled.

Comment: you should be able to post a _complete_ usable plain text file using `example-image.pdf` and showing the error that you ask about, and without using local paths like `c:/dos/belfry`  see the code in Ulrike's answer.

Comment: don't post to an external link: the example should be inline. (The question is archived forever and should make sense as it stands even if that link, which I had missed) breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems to use eplain and graphicx in a current miktex:

```
\input eplain
\input miniltx
\input graphicx.sty

\def\graph#1#2#3{
     \includegraphics[height=#3]{#1.pdf}}
     
\graph{example-image-duck}{}{4cm}     

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It did not work for me with the current miktex, but I can't re-check that at the moment because I no longer have the current miktex installed.   I will find time to re-install and check this later, and if it still doesn't work, I will post the error log.

Comment: I just want to make sure we're clear on this:  When you say you had no problems, you were using pdftex, yes?

Comment: sure. pdfLaTeX wouldn't work, it would error.

Comment: Thank you again.  I just ran this (exactly as you have it, without any references to my local files) and it did in fact work.  (This is with my home-brewed MikTeX installed, the one that overwrites all the current files with old files.)  When I have a break in my schedule, I'll try again with the current MikTeX.  (I still wish very much that it were possible to simply download old versions of MikTeX, for compatibility with whatever little tweaks one has made over the years.)